# Is there a way to get an ItemList back from a PayPal Sale ID?

Tags: php, paypal, e-commerce

I would like to retrieve information about each item sold in a PayPal transaction. They were loaded into a Transaction object at the point of sale: `$transaction->setItemList($itemList);`, but were not stored on a local database.

I only have access to sale and payment ID's. Using the PayPal API, how can I get the list of items back?

Maybe I'm not looking at the API docs hard enough, but I can't seem to find any info about this.

Comment: Are you using the Classic or REST API?

Comment: I'm using the REST API with the PHP SDK interface

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can retrieve the item list details(assuming that you passed to the PayPal)  using the Payment ID's via the Look Up API call . You can check the below link for the API call:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#look-up-a-payment-resource

I have included the call to one of my Payment ID in sandbox account :

```
GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-9NS54822BJ985714GKQ5RH2Y

{
"id": "PAY-9NS54822BJ985714GKQ5RH2Y",
"create_time": "2014-10-12T23:51:07Z",
"update_time": "2014-10-12T23:57:54Z",
"state": "approved",
"intent": "sale",
"payer": {
"payment_method": "paypal",
"status": "VERIFIED",
"payer_info": {
"email": "XXXXXXX",
"first_name": "XXXX Personal Test",
"last_name": "Account",
"payer_id": "XXXXX",
"shipping_address": {
"line1": "cxas",
"line2": "asa",
"city": "FL",
"state": "FL",
"postal_code": "95616",
"country_code": "US",
"recipient_name": "XXXXXPersonal Test Account"
},
"phone": "408-767-7151"
}
},
"transactions": [
{
"amount": {
"total": "20.00",
"currency": "USD",
"details": {
"subtotal": "18.00",
"tax": "1.00",
"shipping": "1.00"
}
},
"description": "This is payment description.",
"item_list": {
"items": [
{
"name": "Hat",
"sku": "product12345",
"price": "2.00",
"currency": "USD",
"quantity": "3",
"description": "This is desc"
},
{
"name": "Hat",
"sku": "product12345",
"price": "2.00",
"currency": "USD",
"quantity": "3",
"description": "This is desc"
},
{
"name": "Hat",
"sku": "product12345",
"price": "2.00",
"currency": "USD",
"quantity": "3",
"description": "This is desc"
}
]
},
"related_resources": [
{
"sale": {
"id": "0P200860V96590012",
"create_time": "2014-10-12T23:51:07Z",
"update_time": "2014-10-12T23:57:54Z",
"amount": {
"total": "20.00",
"currency": "USD"
},
"payment_mode": "INSTANT_TRANSFER",
"state": "completed",
"protection_eligibility": "ELIGIBLE",
"protection_eligibility_type": "ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED_ELIGIBLE,UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT_ELIGIBLE",
"parent_payment": "PAY-9NS54822BJ985714GKQ5RH2Y",
"transaction_fee": {
"value": "0.88",
"currency": "USD"
},
"links": [
{
"href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/0P200860V96590012",
"rel": "self",
"method": "GET"
},
{
"href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/0P200860V96590012/refund",
"rel": "refund",
"method": "POST"
},
{
"href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-9NS54822BJ985714GKQ5RH2Y",
"rel": "parent_payment",
"method": "GET"
}
]
}
}
]
}
],
"links": [
{
"href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-9NS54822BJ985714GKQ5RH2Y",
"rel": "self",
"method": "GET"
}
]
}
```